# IS there any way to update a record in salesforce using PATCH Method Rest Call

Tags: salesforce-id

IS there any way to update a record in salesforce using PATCH Method Rest Call. Can someone help me how PATCH Method can be used in INBOUND REST API

Comment: Check post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57215/how-can-i-make-a-patch-http-callout-from-apex

Comment: That didnt work out

Comment: did you look in the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm?search_text=patch)?  Please see [ask]