# Manipulate (packaged) Flow using Apex

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, visual-workflow, metadata-api, isv

In my Managed Package I have a `Flow` template which subscriber can clone/reuse and customize to their needs. I now want to provide a bite more guidance on such a customization and relate a packaged `Custom Object` to such a flow including code which should do the following.

Is that possible with `Apex` and/or any API?

- Clone a packaged `Flow`
- related it to a `Custom Object` record
- also related the Custom Object to the flow instance
- Modify some variable values in the flow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salesforce has exposed tooling api that can help you clone the Managed Package flow if it is packaged as template.

Note you can wrap this tooling api via an apex class and achieve everything that API can do.

To clone the flow via the api follow the below steps.

**PREREQUSITE** : Note that for experiment i have installed a flow package here from [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMYhpUAH) that comes with a template flow.

**Step 1** - **You will need to query the [flow tooling object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flow.htm) with the template using the tooling api**

The query would look something like below

```
/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query?q=+Select+DefinitionId,+Description,+Metadata,+MasterLabel,++FullName++FROM+Flow+where+MasterLabel='Questionnaire+Subflow'
```

I found a very weird thing that it does not let me filter by the flow api name and had to use Master Label. I suggest if you are using Master label have a namespace prefix of the package to the label of flow. You can also use the **IsTemplate** boolean flag to filter for Template one and also use **ManageableState** field for filter

The response from the API would look like [below](https://gist.github.com/msrivastav13/d6e44349d4f709d3c92df12becb2435b)

The key is to understand the Metadata field. The Metadata will be of the Structure as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm)

**Step 2** - Create a new Flow Sobject with the Metadata similar to the one that you queried.

You can make a POST call to an endpoint as below

```
/services/data/v49.0/tooling/sobjects/Flow
```

A sample JSON to post will be is as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/msrivastav13/945ea929d364738f104843f0eaa82c1f)

A successful POST would response as below

```
{
  "id" : "301B00000006siGIAQ",
  "success" : true,
  "errors" : [ ],
  "warnings" : [ ],
 "infos" : [ {
    "message" : "Example info message"
   } ]
}
```

Note that you will need to copy Metadata field from previous, however make sure that **isTemplate** boolean is false and also you provide a **FullName** field. Do not provide **Master Label** or the **Description** field here.

**Relating to Custom Object**

This can be done by setting a variable **$Flow.CurrentRecord** to the Id of the record. This is documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_recordassoc.htm&type=5).

There is a whole Data Model around this, [FlowInterview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_interviews.htm&type=5) object is the Instance of the flow. The ***FlowInterview*** object is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_flowinterview.htm)

You cannot create these as this are auto created. However you can query them via apex.

[FlowRecordRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_flowrecordrelation.htm) ties flowInterviews and the the Salesforce RecordIds. You can create these records via apex.

**Relating to Custom Object and Modify Variables**

You can update the variables using the PATCH request to the end point as below with the additions,

```
/services/data/v49.0/tooling/sobjects/Flow/<flowID>
```

flowID you can get from the step 2

NOTE: PATCH in apex could be challenging so may require a workaround as mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57215/how-can-i-make-a-patch-http-callout-from-apex).

Flow metadata variables and reference to sobject actions can be updated as well.

Comment: Did your ever make this work using the Apex wrappers that exist for the Tooling https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi or Metadata APIs https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi?

Comment: I tested this using the workbench tool. I think you can simply write a https callout in apex to these endpoint!

Comment: Sure but the parsing, modifying and sending back changes flow metadata is something I have to implement on my own 

Comment: That is true you need an apex wrapper similar to metadata structure. I think you can easily generate one from the JSON using json to apex tool.