# Rest upsert callout

Tags: apex, callout, rest, upsert

How can i make an upsert callout? I have object Contact with custom ExtId with Custom_Object__c id. So i am tried post, patch method and without/with   '?_HttpMethod=PATCH'; What do i need to do? I can only update or insert.  HttpRequestHandler  just do common part.

```
 Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
            headers.put('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + credentials.Access_Token__c);
            headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            headers.put('accept', 'application/json');
`String endpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/contact/' + contact.ExtId__c + '?_HttpMethod=PATCH';`

HttpRequestHandler req = new HttpRequestHandler ('PATCH', body, endpoint, credentials, headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the external id field in the endpoint, like these:

```
String endpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/contact/ExtId__c/' + contact.ExtId__c;
```

If you are doing the callout in Apex, you can check this example to set the HTTP method before and after Winter 21 releasement

[How can I make a PATCH HTTP Callout from Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57215/how-can-i-make-a-patch-http-callout-from-apex)

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm

Comment: oh, thanks. Got it.