# Update conversionRate in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, multi-currency, currencytype

To test some apex functionality, we wanted to update the conversion rates of currencies in a test class. It doesn't work since DML operations aren't allowed on CurrencyType via apex.

Here is more information about the whole sitation:
A custom object holds a certain amount and a currency. There is another field which holds the amount in euros. We wrote a (before insert/before update) trigger on the custom object to calculate the amount in euros based on the conversion rates of the currencies and the 2 fields on the custom object.

Every month the conversion rates will be adjusted, so the euro field also needs to be updated. We wrote a batch process to accomplish this. Now we want to write a test class for the batch process. To write a good test for the functionality, we need to update the conversion rates of the currencies, but it seems it isn't possible through apex.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to insert a new [CurrencyType](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm) or update an existing one?

Either way, based on [Update ConversionRates for CurrencyType from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13258/update-conversionrates-for-currencytype-from-apex), it doesn't appear you can update the ConversionRate via Apex. CurrencyType is also listed in the [sObjects That Don’t Support DML Operations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm).

Its less desirable, but you can use [`Test.isRunningTest()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Test_isRunningTest.htm) to return conversion rates for testing. I.e. wrap all your code that accesses the conversionRate in a single class. Then, in this class, return the actual value unless Test.isRunningTest() is true. In which case you can return a mock value to simulate changes during testing.

Comment: I am trying to update an existing CurrencyType. As you mentioned, it doesn't seem to be possible to update the ConversionRate through apex. I was just wondering if there is a workaround for it. At the moment it means I am not able to write a good test class for the batch process.

Comment: My only idea currently is to return fake data with Test.isRunningTest(). There appears to be a lot happening behind the scenes when you edit a conversion rate - See ("Changing conversion rates causes a mass recalculation of roll-up summary fields")[https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=editing_conversion_rates.htm&language=en]. This is probably part of the reason you can't make the change via apex.